# Video encryption using simple XOR operation

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on video processing project which involves some encryption of video frames using a key image and `XOR` operation. The expression should be as follows,

```
videoframe XOR key_image= modified_video stored in DIVX format

modified_video XOR key_image= not getting original video frame
```

I found that `DIVX` is form of `lossy compression` that's why I am not getting the original video after XORing the modified video with same key image file.

Now I need a simple encryption for video frames (using an image as a key file if possible).

Comment: _ALL_ of the common video formats are "lossy". What you could (probably) do is use the encoded data as your key-image, rather than the unencoded data.

Comment: Also by XORing the pictures you're changing the images in a way so that modern video compression methods can not work efficiently. If you want to encrypt the data, just use a regular block cipher in CBC mode on the output data.